# Moving focus in TextChanged results in "Cannot Undo or Redo while undo unit is open." when doing Ctrl-Z

Tags: wpf, focus, undo, textchanged

I have TextBox1 & TextBox2, TB1 with an OnTextChanged-handler where I move the Focus to the TB2.

Now, if I manually focus TB1 again and do Ctrl-Z, I get the message `"Cannot Undo or Redo while undo unit is open."`. Anyone? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be useful for others.

I searched online and came across this message a couple of times but nothing similair to my situation/no solution, but I did see the following at [MSDN for the TextBox.Undo() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.undo.aspx):

```
"The Undo method does not work with the KeyPress or TextChanged events."
```

What I now tried is to do the focussing Async with BeginInvoke.

```
private void TB1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)FocusTB2);
}

public void FocusTB2()
{
    TB2.Focus();
}
```